# Where does NSUserDefaults store data in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Where does NSUserDefaults store data in an iOS application.?
Is it a good programming practice to assign many NSUserDefaults variables in an application ? or it causes any memory management issues.? When this variables are released.?

Comment: They don't have to be "released". They are written to disk.

Comment: More exactly, NSUserDefaults doesn't change when they need to be released. If they did without it, they still do with it, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always preferred to use NSUserDefaults for storing user specific preferences for the application. The values get stored on the device in plist format. You do not need to worry about releasing memory for NSUserDefaults stored data. They are synched with the plist once you call the [[NSUserdefaults ..] synchronize] method.

The only thing you need to worry about is not to use NSUserDefaults for storing sensitive information like passwords. As this plist can be accessed by directly connecting device to mac  and accesssing application space (sandbox) using third party softwares available.

Answer (score 2):

It stores in the Directory structure of the device. I use NSUSerDefaults to store variables that need not be very secure like username, address etc. For more secure information (eg:password) you would use keychain to store the information.

Comment: When this variables are released.?

Comment: You can call resetStandardUserDefaults to release variables from memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/your app unique id/Library/com.appname

This is the path where the data(`NSUserDefaults`) is stored when using Simulator.

When you remove the app from the device the data in the NSUserDefaults will be erased .

Comment: That's not where the data is stored on the device. That's just the iOS simulator.

Comment: I know. But that path is wrong except for the simulator. It's not that way on an iPhone or iPad.

Comment: I told for the simulator only.

Answer (score 1):

The physical location of NSUserDefaults is :

```
 /Library/Preferences/com.yourcompany.appName.plist
```

For more information see :

[NSUserDefaults class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The physical location *may* be there, or it may be in ~/Library/Preferences/, or it may be in the application's container. None of these locations are guaranteed to be used, so don't rely on even those :) just use the API

Comment: @Catfish_Man : True !

Answer (score 0):

Here I share you code, write down in viewDidLoad, you can get the path.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"%@",paths);
```